# Move main menu in wordpress dashboard to be a child of custom post type menu

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have a custom post type menu called Lotto Syndicates using this code:

```
function my_custom_post_lotto_syndicate() {


$labels = array(

    'name'               => _x( 'Lotto Syndicate', 'post type general name' ),

    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Lotto Syndicate', 'post type singular name' ),

    'add_new'            => _x( 'New Lotto Syndicate', 'Lotto Syndicate' ),

    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Lotto Syndicate' ),

    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Lotto Syndicate' ),

    'new_item'           => __( 'New Lotto Syndicate' ),

    'all_items'          => __( 'All Lotto Syndicates' ),

    'view_item'          => __( 'View Lotto Syndicate' ),

    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Lotto Syndicate' ),

    'not_found'          => __( 'No Lotto Syndicate found' ),

    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Lotto Syndicate found in the Trash' ), 

    'parent_item_colon'  => '',

    'menu_name'          => 'Lotto Syndicates'

);

$args = array(

    'labels'        => $labels,

    'description'   => 'Holds our Lotto Syndicate and Lotto Syndicate specific data',

    'public'        => true,

    'menu_position' => 5,

    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),

    'has_archive'   => true,

);

register_post_type( 'Lotto Syndicate', $args ); 


}


add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_lotto_syndicate' );
```

I have also renamed the main users menu in to 'Syndicate Users' and I would like to move that (and also its sub items) to be in my custom post type, here is the code I used to rename the users menu:

```
function change_post_menu_label() {

global $menu;

global $submenu;

$menu[70][0] = 'Syndicate Users';

$submenu['user-new.php'][5][0] = 'Syndicate User';

$submenu['user-new.php'][10][0] = 'Add Syndicate User';

$submenu['users.php'][5][0] = 'All Syndicate Users';

$submenu['users.php'][10][0] = 'Add Syndicate User';

}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_post_menu_label' );
```

I have looked in the wordpress development documentation but I can't find out how to move a main item menu into a custom post type menu, I have found how to move custom post type menu into the main menu but that's not what i want.